# Why can't a general function performs a loop on any given list work

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop

I wrote this function to perform a loop on any list

```
int loop(List list) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int currentValue = i;
    list[currentValue];
  }
}
```

but it says

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'int', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

I added a throw statement but after a single loop the second time, it throws the exception. And I have no idea what to return outside the for-loop.

Comment: Your function doesn't actually do anything.  It iterates over the `List` but doesn't do anything with the elements.  Nobody can tell you what your function should return outside of the loop since you haven't explained what you expect.  If callers shouldn't expect any result, then your function should use a `void` return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned*

Your method return type is `int`, means you need to return a `int` from the method.

```dart
int loop(List list) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int currentValue = i;
    list[currentValue];
  }
  return 0; //any int
}
```